# Correct way to refresh data using Paging library - Database + Network

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging

I have a list of posts which I am fetching using retrofit. I am using the Android Paging library to fetch 20 post at a time.

Let's say this is the second time I am opening the application. I have 2 posts already in the database, one of which is deleted from the server.

As soon as I start activity, I request for new data using BoundaryCallback. Before I fetch new data, I delete the data which is in the database which is causing the problem. As I am using the boundary callback the empty data is shown to the user with "No records" image view and then the new data is shown.

I am trying to avoid the update which shows the no records view.

This is really annoying, last year I downloaded the GitHub architecture components samples from Google without paging and they tried to avoid these problem in the sample application instead of solving it. In short, they didn't delete the old data, but fetched new one. It could be that the samples from Google are always incomplete or they are expecting us to add our own implementation for it (I don't believe this "or").

Instead of removing I tried to use the on conflict strategy to replace the existing data. But I found it does not remove the old one.

```
// BoundaryCallback file

class PostBoundaryCallback (

    ):
    PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Post>() {


    private var lastRequestedPage = 1

    init {
        if(reset) {
            // Deleting when flag is reset
            appExecutors.diskIO().execute {
                repository.delete(groupId)
            }
            lastRequestedPage = 1
        }
    }

    override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
        repository.requestAndSaveData(groupId, lastRequestedPage, userId)
    }

    override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Post) {
        if(reset) {
            lastRequestedPage = 1
            reset = false
        } else {
            lastRequestedPage += 1
        }

        repository.requestAndSaveData(groupId, lastRequestedPage, userId)
    }

}
```

// ViewModel file

```
var postsForUser : LiveData<PagedList<Post>> = Transformations.switchMap(_resetAllPostsForUser) {

        val factory = postDao.allPostsForUserWith(it.first)
        factory.create()
        val boundaryCallback = PostUserBoundaryCallback(it.first, repository, it.second, appExecutors)
        LivePagedListBuilder(factory, 10)
            .setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback)
            .setFetchExecutor(appExecutors.diskIO())
            .build()
        }
```

// Activity

```
viewModel.posts.observe(this, Observer {
            if(it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                noPostsLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                noPostsLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            adapter.submitList(it)
            if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing ) {
            dswipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
}
            hideProgressView()
})
```

Comment: Do you have new solution?